# Refreshing browser makes data disappear in Kendo UI Grid (MVC ASP.NET)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

My Kendo UI Grid is working perfectly except I'm having an issue with page refreshes. I noticed that if I refresh the browser, the data that I just inserted disappears. The cells are still there because the Grid recognizes that there should be data and the Read action method is firing and returning the appropriate data, but the data just doesn't show up. Any ideas?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult EditingPopup_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ExpenseReportModel erLineItem, int expenseReportId)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(globalKip.DisplayExpenseReportLineItems_Employee(expenseReportId).ToList().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Index", erLineItem);
        }
    }
```

Grid markup:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ExpenseReport.MVC.Models.ExpenseReportModel>()
        .Name("Grid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(p => p.ExpenseReportId).Visible(true);
                columns.Bound(p => p.ExpenseLineItemId).Visible(true);
                columns.Bound(p => p.ExpenseTypeDesc).Title("Expense Type");
                columns.Bound(p => p.City).Title("City");
                columns.Bound(p => p.StateName).Title("State");
                columns.Bound(p => p.Date).Format("{0:d}").Title("Date");
                columns.Bound(p => p.Amount).Title("Amount");
                columns.Bound(p => p.EndingMileage).Title("Ending Mileage");
                columns.Bound(p => p.BeginningMileage).Title("Beginning Mileage");
                columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); });
            })
            .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().HtmlAttributes(new { id = "btnAdd" }))
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("NewExpense").Window(w => w.Width(500)))
            .Pageable()            
            .Scrollable()            
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px; width=100%" })            
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)
                //.Events(events => events.Sync("onRequestStart"))
                .Model(model => model.Id("ExpenseLineItemId"))
                .Create(create => create
                    .Action("EditingPopup_Create", "ExpenseReport")
                    .Data("erLineItemsCreateData"))
                .Read(read => read
                    .Action("EditingPopup_Read", "ExpenseReport")
                    .Data("erLineItemsReadData"))
                .Update(update => update
                    .Action("EditingPopup_Update", "ExpenseReport"))                    
                .Destroy(destroy => destroy
                    .Action("EditingPopup_Destroy", "ExpenseReport").Type(HttpVerbs.Post)))           
    )

//pass additional data to the READ action method
        function erLineItemsReadData() {
            return {
                expenseReportId: "@ViewBag.ExpenseReportId"
            };
        }

        function erLineItemsCreateData() {
            return {
                expenseReportId: "@ViewBag.ExpenseReportId"
                };
        }

        function erLineItemsUpdateData() {
            return {
                expenseReportId: "@ViewBag.ExpenseReportId"

                };
        }
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to fix part of the problem. Please see code below. Now, when I create a row, the row is maintained after a browser refresh. However, now when the page first loads, a new blank row is inserted into the grid. I do not want this behavior. Also, if I add more than 1 row and refresh the page, all but the last row I created disappears.

```
public ActionResult EditingPopup_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ExpenseReportModel erLineItem, int expenseReportId)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {

            var results = globalKip.DisplayExpenseReportLineItems_Employee(expenseReportId).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
            {
                erLineItem.ExpenseReportId = (int)results[i].ERL_EPR_ID;
                erLineItem.ExpenseLineItemId = results[i].ERL_ID;
                erLineItem.ExpenseTypeDesc = results[i].ERL_ExpenseType;
                erLineItem.City = results[i].ERL_City;
                erLineItem.StateName = results[i].ERL_State;
                erLineItem.Date = (DateTime)results[i].ERL_Date;
                erLineItem.Amount = (Decimal)results[i].ERL_DollarAmount;
                erLineItem.EndingMileage = (int)results[i].ERL_EndingMileage;
                erLineItem.BeginningMileage = (int)results[i].ERL_BeginningMileage;
            }

            //return Json(new[] { erLineItem }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));

            return Json(new[] { erLineItem }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));


            //return Json(globalKip.DisplayExpenseReportLineItems_Employee(expenseReportId).ToList().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Index", erLineItem);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you verify that newly inserted data also present in the db...after insertion

Comment: Yes it is there. That's what is making me wonder what's going on. I did, actually fix part of the problem, please see the update above.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The field names returned from the stored procedure results do not match the field names in my model. I renamed them and fixed the entire problem with another slight modification (using an IQuerable rather than a for loop).